# "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Tags: c#, console, environment, quit

I am getting this error in my code for a c# console application

```
 case 5:
    Console.WriteLine("User selected to Quit, option " + response);
    Environment.Exit;
    break;
```

// Error       Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: C# is not VB.NET, methods need brackets as per Evil Penguin's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Environment.Exit` is a method - you need to add brackets to call it:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Edit:  sorry, I should have paid more attention. Added the argument.  Thanks 0_**_**_0

Comment: //error       No overload for method 'Exit' takes 0 arguments

Answer (score 1):

Since Enviroment.Exit is a method, so you need to do

```
Enviroment.Exit(0);
```

Here 0 is the intcode provided to OS.

You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is more generic answer "got error - what to do" as you already have answer to your particular question: `Environment.Exit` is not a call.

All C# compiler errors have error code associated with it. I.e. in your case you'll see something like this in output:Compile window:

> CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

MSDN already provides explanations for a lot of common errors. Basic search for error code http://www.bing.com/search?q=CS0201 instantly gives you link to the article on MSDN - [Compiler Error CS0201](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k626bk8b.aspx).  In your particular case it may not have helped (as linked article is not covering this case) but consider such search as first step in future when you encounter unclear error.